# What would database-schema/database-design look like for google analytics?

Tags: database-design, google-analytics, database-schema

I would like to keep track of the same data that I am sending to GA tracking, and would like our own home-grown event table.  What would Google's database schema look like for their events/GoogleAnalytics.

So far I have, one event table with the following columns, and am wondering if i'm missing anything major:

### Event

```
id
event-type (ie. event, page-view, custom-var, identity)
domain (ie. sub.main.com, sub2.main.com)
page-url (ie /questions/popular)
action-name (ie. "clicked sign in", "signed up")
session_id (to keep track of entire experience)
user_id (could be nil)
utm_vars (GA source, medium, campaign, etc.)
is_mobile
created_at (timestamp)
data-properties (a hash of other random properties that are being tracked, like "clicked from header", "clicked from footer")
```

Comment: The answer to this depends on what you are wanting to track. If you already have the information available to your server-side code then you can easily populate the database with that information.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google is using some massive noSql-thingie, so talking about Googles database schema might be a bit misleading (your schema looks fine for what you want to do, though, and I guess that was your question).

If you want to make sure you have the same data google has you can send the raw data to you own server using the following methods:

```
_gaq.push(['_setLocalGifPath', 'http://yourdomain/phpscript_masking-as-image.gif']);
_gaq.push(['_setLocalRemoteServerMode']);
```

(These were intended to be processed by the self-hosted, now discontinued urchin analytics product that used the same format as GA).

This function will send the request for the utm tracking gif with the appended tracking data to both GA and your own server. You can write a PHP script that masks as gif and parses the tracking requests for events (more likely you want to write to information to a file and parse it in the background as to not bring you server down - GA sends quite a lot of gifs). That way you do not need to think about your own data collection mechanism.