# Raw data in analytics

Tags: magento, google-analytics

I would like to have the data in my site individually. For example: visitant 1 visited page 1, page 2, page 3, at time x,y,z.
How can i get this data in analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot see data for individual visitors in GA (and trying to do so would violate Googles Terms of Service).

You can redirect the tracking calls to your own server and write a script to parse for visitor data, see me answer here:

[What would database-schema/database-design look like for google analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324676/what-would-database-schema-database-design-look-like-for-google-analytics/13363905#13363905)

(Those methods served for compatibility with the Urchin analytics software - since support for Urchin was dropped it might be that those method will be dropped at some point in the future).